# How to Compute Sum of Dictionary Field in Spark with Python?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, reduce, rdd

My data is saved in an Spark RDD and it is structured as such:

```
survivors.take(3)
Out[45]:
[{'Age': '38',
  'Cabin': 'C85',
  'Embarked': 'C',
  'Fare': '71.2833',
  'Name': 'Cumings, Mrs. John Bradley (Florence Briggs Thayer)',
  'Parch': '0',
  'PassengerId': '2',
  'Pclass': '1',
  'Sex': 'female',
  'SibSp': '1',
  'Survived': '1',
  'Ticket': 'PC 17599'},
 {'Age': '26',
  'Cabin': '',
  'Embarked': 'S',
  'Fare': '7.925',
  'Name': 'Heikkinen, Miss. Laina',
  'Parch': '0',
  'PassengerId': '3',
  'Pclass': '3',
  'Sex': 'female',
  'SibSp': '0',
  'Survived': '1',
  'Ticket': 'STON/O2. 3101282'},
 {'Age': '35',
  'Cabin': 'C123',
  'Embarked': 'S',
  'Fare': '53.1',
  'Name': 'Futrelle, Mrs. Jacques Heath (Lily May Peel)',
  'Parch': '0',
  'PassengerId': '4',
  'Pclass': '1',
  'Sex': 'female',
  'SibSp': '1',
  'Survived': '1',
  'Ticket': '113803'}]
```

I would like to calculate the sum of the "Age" column for the dictionary above, using reduce. I am trying to do it as such:

```
survivors.reduce(lambda row, acc: acc + float(row['Age']))
```

However, I am not having any luck. I am no python expert, so perhaps this is a python problem.

Comment: You have only an argument. Reduce method needs two at least two argument. you call this method as reduce(function, list). Read this https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#reduce

Answer (score 0):

I would use a sum map instead.

```
 sum(list(map(lambda row: row['Age'],survivors.take(3))))
```

Comment: This does not work, I get the following error.
`TypeError: 'PipelinedRDD' object is not iterable`
Does it have something to do with 'survivors' being an RDD in Spark?

Comment: From your output, survivors.take(3) is a list of dictionaries. I'll update the solution.

Answer (score 0):

You've got the arguments of the reduce the wrong way around, you need to have the accumulator first, also you need to make the accumulator into a dict.

```
survivors.reduce(lambda acc, row: {'Age': float(acc['Age']) + float(row['Age'])})
```